# add Storage Driver with devicemaper value on Windows Docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I needed to find the Docker configuration file on Windows to change `storage-driver` attrib.
This information is showed with `docker info` command.

Comment: What's your higher-level goal?  I'd generally suggest avoiding devicemapper if you have another functional option; this seems like an awfully specific request.

Answer (score 0):

You can go the following path: `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources` and look up two files:

1. `linux-daemon-options.json`
2. `windows-daemon-options.json`

and check the attrib: `"storage-driver": ""` and then, change for: `"storage-driver": "devicemapper",`